# interpolating/backfilling missing data/0s by calculated ratio using R

Tags: r

hi i'm curious about using a ratio of values between two columns (see c1 and c2 below) to multiply against a preceding value in one column to fill the other column where data is NA or 0.

i have a large data set sorted by year and US state, and would like to run this so it looks through c1 for the first instance that the data is not missing, uses the next row to find a ratio between c1 and c2, and backfills all the earlier 0 years of c1 by multiplying c2 by that ratio.

any direction you can offer would be appreciated. i'm not even sure where to start on this one...

```
y <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
c1 <- c(0, 0 , 0, 5.4, 5.5, 5.8)
c2 <- c(4.4, 4.5, 4.8, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3)
df <- data.frame(y, c1, c2)
```

Comment: What is your expected output given this sample input?

Comment: FYI, your code is missing a leading `c`, currently it is a parsing error. Please try the code you give us in a fresh R instance to ensure it works.

Comment: Hi @user12345, Stack disincentivizes us from both answering a question and advising new users to be contributing members of the Stack community. As such, I'll advise: please consider going back to your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18048351/gered?tab=questions) and accepting answers by clicking on the check-mark; this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. (I hope somebody else answers your question, as now I cannot.)

Comment: expected output would be 0s are filled for earlier years based on the ratio of the first year where data exists in both columns. i dont need an answer just guidance on where to start looking in resources thanks.

Comment: `ratios <- df$c1 / df$c2; ratios[!ratios > 0] <- ratios[ratios > 0][1]; ifelse(c1 > 0, c1, c2*ratios)`, I still don't know what your expected values are, perhaps this is enough.

Comment: this is really interesting and not something i have seen before thank you! i'm curious about how the [ratios >0][1] works here. to check it i added another row of data before the 0 rows (c1 = 1, c2 = 1.2) and the 0 rows filled with the ratio from row 1. When i changed it to [ratios >0][2] 0 rows were filled with the ratio from the 4.9/5.4 row. this is actually the ideal, although i'm not sure why calling 2 vs 1 did this. is there a specific reference guide you could point me to for these kind of calculations? thank you @r2evans

Comment: No reference guide. You're looking at something akin to "next observation carried backward" (nocb) which is provided by `zoo::na.locf` ("locf" is for last observation carried forward, the reverse-direction of the same operation) as well as `tidyr::fill`, but those functions are replacing based on `NA` values, not `0`s (since though you say "data exists" suggesting 0 is not data, `0` is perfectly good data with a clear quantity. Perhaps if you use `ratios[abs(df$c1) < 1e-9] <- NA`, you could adapt `zoo::na.locf` to your needs. Happy reading.

Comment: ok i ended up using na.locf backwards by group and it worked nicely, although couldn't get it all to happen within the original column. had to make some new vars. your suggestions were very helpful thank you!